# How to create big style comment for HTML templates

Tags: html, comments

If you look at the source code of some HTML sites, they use some giant alphabets to comment out or to provide their site name. Something where you write the word and it converts to to HTML like below:

```
<!--
------   
-
---
-
------
!-->
```

anyone know how to create these types of comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Google "[Big ASCII text art](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=Big+ASCII+text+art&oq=Big+ASCII+text+art&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)" and you'll find several online generators.

For example, here's one from [bigtext.org](http://bigtext.org/):

```
    _       _                 
   / \   __| | __ _ _ __ ___  
  / _ \ / _` |/ _` | '_ ` _ \ 
 / ___ \ (_| | (_| | | | | | |
/_/   \_\__,_|\__,_|_| |_| |_|
```

[Here's another website](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/) that lets you customize the font and a few other things. Example (using the font 'tinker-toy'):

```
  O     o           
 / \    |           
o---o o-O  oo o-O-o 
|   ||  | | | | | | 
o   o o-o o-o-o o o
```